# HP Plotter 1050c plus

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, plotter

I have an (1998 manual) old plotter HP PLotter 1050c Plus (only works on Windows XP)... It prints fine, but the Source/Receivers are not showing up on the map nor the legend.  Everything else is displayed.  It is printing off the Adobe PDF created by ArcGIS 10.1

Not sure what the problem is, I have increased the size of the Src/Rec, but not luck. Troubleshooting manual is no help either.

Has anyone experienced this problem and fixed it?

Comment: How are you sending the file to the plotter PDF, PRN? We have a 1050cm no xp here only windows 7. The drivers are here [Pentium 1 GB RAM memory Win XP, Win 2K3, Windows Vista, 2K8 and Win-7 Firmware version: A.04.02]
 http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=24023&prodNameId=12607&swEnvOID=2100&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=pl-37410-7

Comment: PDF.  HP said they no longer have drivers available, except for universal.  That universal driver was fine...  We have the parallel cable from the Plotter to Desktop.  

The map prints out fine on other printers 8x11 etc. The Plotter just won't print out the Source / Receivers (Plots), the company logo and any other images.  

I don't know if the printheads, old machine/wear and tear is the issue?

Comment: We do use posterjet for (Raster Image Processing) RIP software. http://www.posterjet.com/en/products/ always prints (starts printing in 7 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluebeam PDF fixed the issue as Adobe PDF nor CutePDF worked with this particular plotter.

Answer (score 1):

Having run into similar problems with virtual PDF printers myself, I would suggest instead using the [File - Export Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_your_map/00sm00000004000000/) functionality to [export to PDF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_to_PDF/00sm00000007000000/).

This will in general be more compatible and functional (especially if you choose to include georeferencing info, map layers, feature attributes, etc.)